# ping statistics

Tags: ping, statistics

When `ping` displays statistics the field `mdev` is the std deviation of all the ping times. It is the average time (in ms) to the average `avg`.

But because ping times are stricktly positive, I don't understand how `mdev` could be higher than twice the value of `avg`, like in this case:

I've got this ping times:

```
[...]
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=76 ttl=128 time=1.95 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
76 packets transmitted, 76 received, 0% packet loss, time 75097ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.617/13.289/468.557/66.726 ms
```

where `mdev` is five times `avg`.

EDIT: raw data: 1.91,2.83,4.41,1.83,2.98,2.18,2.15,1.68,2.30,2.04,1.64,1.98,1.69,1.88,1.91,1.83,1.70,2.00,2.03,1.89,2.36,2.12,2.07,1.91,1.84,2.04,2.05,2.10,2.19,2.22,1.94,2.13,1.98,2.08,1.62,3.29,2.17,1.99,2.38,2.55,2.16,1.90,1.92,1.90,2.89,2.04,2.05,2.12,2.18,1.61,2.08,1.90,2.17,3.01,1.84,2.12,20.9,362,2.07,2.31,2.42,2.05,2.47,2.55,2.13,2.56,2.07,468,2.33,2.32,1.93,1.87,2.50,1.82,2.45,1.95

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last value, labeled `mdev` under Linux and `stddev` under Solaris is computed slightly differently depending on these OSes.

The formula used by [Linux ping](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/master/ping_common.c) is:

```
sqrt(smean-mean²)
```

while the one used by [Solaris ping](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/master/usr/src/cmd/cmd-inet/usr.sbin/ping/ping.c) is:

```
sqrt((smean-mean²)*received/received-1)
```

with `smean` being the mean of `rtt` squares, `mean` the mean of `rtt` values and `received` the number of answers received.

Here is a small `awk` program using your data and showing how are computed these values.

```
echo "1.91 2.83 4.41 1.83 2.98 2.18 2.15 1.68 2.30 2.04 1.64 1.98 1.69 1.88
1.91 1.83 1.70 2.00 2.03 1.89 2.36 2.12 2.07 1.91 1.84 2.04 2.05 2.10 2.19
2.22 1.94 2.13 1.98 2.08 1.62 3.29 2.17 1.99 2.38 2.55 2.16 1.90 1.92 1.90
2.89 2.04 2.05 2.12 2.18 1.61 2.08 1.90 2.17 3.01 1.84 2.12 20.9 362 2.07
2.31 2.42 2.05 2.47 2.55 2.13 2.56 2.07 468 2.33 2.32 1.93 1.87 2.50 1.82
2.45 1.95" | awk '
function abs(v) {return v < 0 ? -v : v}
BEGIN {
  min=0x7fffffff;
}
{
  for(i=0;i<NF;i++) {
    received++
    v=$i
    min=v<min?v:min;
    max=v>max?v:max;
    sum+=v
    sum2+=v*v
  }
}
END {
  mean=sum/received
  smean=sum2/received
  printf("received=%d, min=%f, avg=%f, max=%f\n",received,min,sum/received,max)
  printf("Linux ping mdev: %f\n", sqrt(smean-(mean*mean)))
  printf("Solaris ping stddev: %f\n", sqrt(((smean-(mean*mean))*received)/(received-1)))
}
'
```

Its output is consistent with your test:

```
received=76, min=1.610000, avg=13.294211, max=468.000000
Linux ping mdev: 66.632781
Solaris ping stddev: 67.075529
```

Comment: I see. I've added the data to the initial post, it makes sense once plotted: all of the times are within a few ms, very close to ~2.5ms and only 3 outliers are far away (2ms, 360ms, 468ms). These 3 outliers ruin the avg. But I'd exoect the stddev to be much lower than 66ms because in average the times are within a few ms from `avg` (if not less). A stddev of 66ms which represent "the average to the average" is misleading.

Comment: If I remove these 3 outliers, the stddev becomes 0.42 ms !!! So my belief (the common belief, actually) that the stddev represents the average to the average is wrong: in this instance the average to `avg` is closer to ~0.5 ms than 66 ms. Mystery solved, thanks!

Comment: The standard deviation is not the mean absolute deviation. These metrics are numerically similar, but mathematically different. The standard deviation is calculated using squared distances. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation

Comment: @Deleet Thanks for your wise comment. I looked to the actual source code and updated my answer to show how this is actually computed.